# ¿Cómo definir el ancho de un <div> tag?

Tags: java, css, jsp, struts

Soy nuevo en el uso de la librería Struts, así que les expongo lo siguiente.

Tengo este código en un archivo JSP:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!-- Código head y body -->
<div class="dashboard-wrapper" width="100%">
    <div class="left-sidebar" width="40%">
        <h1>¡Trabajadores!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="left-sidebar" width="60%">
        <h1>¡Holi!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Más código body -->
```

Pero cuando lo compilo y despliego el archivo `*.war`, los dos mensajes aparecen uno debajo del otro. Mi idea es poder tener dos etiquetas `<div />`, de tal forma que estén alineados horizontalmente.

¿Alguien sabe qué debo usar, o a qué propiedad CSS debo invocar para poder ajustar el ancho de un div adecuadamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con bootstrap es algo sencillo porque se maneja una grid para eso

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>¡Trabajadores!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>¡Holi!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

y así cómo lo tienes prueba con

```
<div class="dashboard-wrapper" style="width:100%">
    <div class="left-sidebar" style="width:40%">
        <h1>¡Trabajadores!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="left-sidebar" style="width:60%">
        <h1>¡Holi!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```